# Qooxdoo: Reuse desktop classes in mobile application

Tags: javascript, mobile, desktop, qooxdoo

I have a full-grown qooxdoo desktop application and a freshly created mobile application. I want to reuse existing classes from my desktop app in my mobile app. I modified the configuration file so that the compiler knows about the paths.

Just adding a desktop widget to a mobile page is not possible because they seem to be completely incompatible:

```
var title = new myapp.ui.basic.Label("Test");
page1.getContent().add(title);
```

produces:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'add'
```

Is there another way to use desktop classes in a mobile app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Class defined for desktop in mobile apps as well but this excludes widgets. qooxdoo has a separate UI Toolkit optimized for mobile which should be used. The widgets for desktop are different and not compatible. Still, you can reuse all your IO and logic classes without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for inspiration have a look at the [Feedreader](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/tree/release_2_1_1/application/feedreader/source/class/feedreader) application that provides 3 different frontends (desktop, mobile, web) but shares all of the logic.