# Scalable themes in qooxdoo

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm developing an interactive full-screen application using qooxdoo Desktop. The application should deliver consistent user experience on multiple devices, from 1024x600 netbooks to modern 2560x1600 "retina" displays.

The application uses custom widget theme. The problem is, to provide consistent look'n'feel across multiple resolutions we have to adjust parameters like border radius (for buttons) and font size. Do I have to maintain individual themes for each major resolution, or is there more elegant way to do the same?

Comment: themes alone may not be sufficient to create a mobile website. qooxdoo mobile provides classes to deal with touch-based events and widgets that look better on mobile devices. see also my question since i have a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428805/qooxdoo-reuse-desktop-classes-in-mobile-application

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a couple of predefined steps your theme should have, you can use states for that.

1. Patch qx.ui.core.Widget and add the desired states for every widget in the constructor
2. You can access these states in the appearance theme and react set the desired values based on the given state.

Comment: But how to decide which state to use on a given device? Shouldn't he use some media query or qx.core.Environment check?